# Rotate CategoryAxis labels on amcharts4 radar chart

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts4

I'm trying to rotate the CategoryAxis labels on a *amchart Radar Chart*, to place them in a way that makes more sense for radar columns.

All I managed so far was to rotate the whole chart, but what I'm trying to achieve is to to move the category labels (category1, category2, category3 in the example) so that they are placed in the center of the "pie-slice" that holds the category data, instead of at the edge of it.

```js
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);

var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.RadarChart);

chart.data = [{
  "category": "category1",
      "employee1": 100,
      "employee2": 200,
      "employee3": 100,

}, {
  "category": "category2",

      "employee1": 300,
      "employee2": 100,
      "employee3": 150
}, {
  "category": "category3",
    "employee1": 200,
    "employee2": 200,
    "employee3": 250
}];

var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "category";
var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());

var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

let series1= chart.series.push(new am4charts.RadarColumnSeries());      
series1.dataFields.valueY = "employee1";
series1.dataFields.categoryX = "category";
    
let series2= chart.series.push(new am4charts.RadarColumnSeries());      
series2.dataFields.valueY = "employee2";
series2.dataFields.categoryX = "category";
    
let series3= chart.series.push(new am4charts.RadarColumnSeries());      
series3.dataFields.valueY = "employee3";
series3.dataFields.categoryX = "category";
```

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}

#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work out.

Do the following for all 4 series:

```
let valueLabel = series1.columns.template.createChild(am4core.Label)
valueLabel.text = '{employee1}'
valueLabel.fontSize = 14
valueLabel.valign = 'top'
valueLabel.fill = am4core.color('#fff')
valueLabel.rotation = 270
valueLabel.dy = 10
valueLabel.strokeWidth = 0
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

So, I found an answer to this questions:

```
 let valueLabel = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.LabelBullet())
 valueLabel.label.text = '{value}'
 valueLabel.locationX = 1
 valueLabel.dx = -30
 valueLabel.fontSize = 14
```